# User provisioning script for Exchange and AD?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2007, scripting, provisioning

I'm currently running Exchange 2007 and Windows Server 2003 ADs.  If I wanted to create a user creation/deletion script that would create and delete users, what would be the best way of dealing with this?  Powershell from the Exchange server?  Some of the things I'd like to do....

- I'd like to be able to create the AD user
- Assign a profile path, profile login script and home folder
- Set password to change on next logon
- Assign security group membership
- Assign Distribution group membership
- Hide a user upon termination (keep mailbox, assign permissions to mailbox to manager or forward e-mails, hide from address list, remove from distribution groups)
- Delete a user upon/after termination (delete mailbox & user)

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used CSVDE for some scripted Active Directory actions. Here's a couple pages that will introduce the tool for you:

- [CSVDE and Active Directory (Technet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772704%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Importing Users with CSVDE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327620) (Written for 2000, but still relevant)
- [Guide to bulk/scripted user imports](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/Logon_CSVDE_Bulk.htm)

There are other alternatives to csvde, such as Powershell [as described here quite well](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2007/05/14/create-an-ad-user-in-powershell.aspx)

Deleting a user account is much easier, since all you need to do is remove the record in AD. Here's a page from MS on doing it with VBScript: [ADSI Scriptomatic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939958)

Now, mailbox actions with Exchange 2007 will require PowerShell cmdlets. Here's a guide on how to accomplish this: [MSExchange.org User Administration Guide](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/user-administration-exchange-2007-powershell-cmdlets.html). You can also create entire accounts with this particular cmdlet (New-Mailbox), but it's not as granular as csvde or the other powershell tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell. Here is a 4 part series (including screencast) to get you started. [Automating User Provisioning, Part 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.windowspowershell.aspx)